# Loopback component storage creating APIs to displaying folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, loopbackjs

I have been able to connect the loopback framework to the Amazon S3 account, to create REST APIs from it. However the information it displays is only at the container and file level for the entire account.

My goal is to create APIs that would allow a user to write different levels of folder names then display the contents of that path.

for example:
parent
  child1
    child1-child
      toys.txt
  child2
    notes.txt
    child2-child
      toys.txt

so if the user inputs parent/child2 the rest api should display the contents from there onwards ie {notes.txt, child2-child/} to a depth of 1

I have been able to hardwire a single bucket in the `getFiles` function in `storage-service.js`:

```
StorageService.prototype.getFiles = function (container, options, cb) {
  ...
  return this.client.getFiles('hardwiredbucketname', options, function (err, files) {
...
};
```

and now would like to create APIs that would allow me to specify the folder name and display all its contents to a single depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note here is that there are no folders in S3. S3 has flat structure. You should read [Working with S3 folders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html) first.

When working with S3 from node the best thing to do is to use [AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html). In order get folder contents you can create remote method that will accept path argument on your storage model and then you can use [listObjecstV2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) method to get object list.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3()
var params = {
  Bucket: 'hardwiredbucketname',
  Prefix: 'parent/',
  Delimiter: '/'
};
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data){
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Take the 'data' object from callback then parse 'Contents' and 'CommonPrefixes' property to get your files and folders.